# What will happen if I install Windows 8.1 32 bit on a 64 bit PC?

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory, 64-bit, 32-bit

I found that my PC can run a 64 bit OS, but my RAM is only 1.5 GB. Am I doing something wrong by installing windows 8.1 32 bit? Is my system capable of performing better? What happens if I install the 32 bit version of the OS on a 64 bit processor?

[image]

and these are my specifications:

[image]

Comment: i need more answers to this question. please my dear superuser community

Comment: Why do you need more answers? What's wrong with the one already given? This is not a place to take polls.

Comment: first, it is fine to run 32bit software on x64 hardware. second, you seem concerned about your ram. do you expect to have more of it than 1.5GB? how much RAM is actually installed?

Comment: What will happen is you will have a 64-bit operating system.  All 64-bit processors are 32-bit processors with the x86-64 extension.  This question is popular, I have seen this exact question ( always slightly modified ), several times I always mention the fact all 64-bit processors are 32-bit processors with said extension.

Comment: It will open a worm hole and devour planet earth....

Answer (score 1):

With only 1.5G  of RAM 64 bit will be a waste honestly the MAIN and most common advantage of 64 bit (x86_64)  is the fully optimized use of RAM over 4Gb  (without PAE)..  64  bit systems can  either 32 and 64  bit OSes however the reverse is a major  no-go.    In short, given the lower specs the 32 Bit OS is better for your use-case..

Answer (score 0):

With your current amount of RAM its better to continue with 32 bit.
when you upgrade your ram over 2 Gb upgrade your os to 64 bit as there is a ram limit for 32 bit. Hope its clear.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, almost everything will work ok, but some programs will not.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It does exactly provide excellent, concise answer to the question "What happens if I install the 32 bit version of the OS on a 64 bit processor?".